# Hcl me connect V1 lockscreen error

Tags: lock-screens

I installed Google play in my HCL ME V1 tablet. It was working fine, when i restarted the tablet, my pattern unlock type changes to swipe screen unlock, and when I swipe it to unlock the screen the lock fades away and does not unlock.

What can I do to solve this issue?